# "Looking right at............" is it correct to say that?

Tags: phrases, prepositions

If I want to describe a place that is straight in front of a building, can I say that this place is "looking right at" that building?

Comment: You want to say something like "The Embassy is looking right at the Central Station"? Or describing where **you** are, "I am looking right at the Central Station"?

Comment: I don't think it's idiomatic to use emphatic ***looking right at X*** in contexts where the subject is ***inanimate and/or immobile***, and the intended sense is that X is directly in front of the subject. If the inanimate/immobile subject is *bigger* than X, you might say *It **overlooks** X*, and even if not, you can say *It **looks** [directly] **out to** X*, but *It's looking right at X* doesn't work for me when both the subject and X are things like buildings. That's a metaphor too far, in my book.

Comment: You say one building looks out at another, or looks into another, which might be what you're thinking of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest

> *[This place]* **faces** *[that building]*.
>
> The embassy **faces** Central Station.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/face) has

> **face**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **1** Be positioned with the face or front towards (someone or something).
> *On the bungalow the porch faces the ocean.*

Answer (score 1):

I would say "the office is located directly opposite from the station", or "the office faces the station".

See verb, with object, definition of "[to face](https://www.lexico.com/definition/face)"

Both imply that they are in a position where both buildings could "look right at" each other, if they had the power of sight.